# Mech challenge rate

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, conversion, dragonmech

I'm trying to use some material from Dragonmech to spice up my next Eberron campaign. Since it' s licensed under the D20, aside from some strange damage type, I hadn't any problem with implementig the rules in 3.5e.
Until I get to the "Mech gallery" (starting at page 98) and i realised that there is no CR or CR modifier for the Mech.
**How can I enstablish the impact that a Mech have on a fight ?**
Is it already written somewhere and I missed it? If there is no rule about it I'm open to houserule, if already tested.

---

As a side note, I'm aware that the pilot, with his class choice and his skill\bab, influence the CR of a fight, but I think the Mech itself should make some difference in a fight.
Fighting a lvl 10 mech jokey on Mech A is different than fighting a lvl 10 warrior on Mech A, but fighting a lvl 10 MJ on mech A is different than fight the same MJ on mech B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to determine a mech's impact on a particular encounter is for the DM to subtract the mech's total cost from the owner's wealth (see Table 4–23: NPC Gear Value (*DMG* 127)) or the encounter's treasure (see Table 3–3: Treasure Values per Encounter (*DMG* 51)), much as one would with any other piece of gear. Mechs are, after all, often just outsized, complicated-to-use-and-play piles of hit points, frequently useless without their operators.

Like a mount, the mech's owner and location are often more important than the mech itself, and a mech's presence in an encounter should prevent the owner from using the resources necessary to acquire the mech for something else, much like, for example, a creature that takes the Leadership feat to gain the service of cohort that functions as a mount can't use that same Leadership feat to gain also the services of, for example, a master magic item creator cohort (unless, of course, the versatile mount can do both).

Comment: I see what you are saying and watching it by this prospective make sense in a mech heavy campaign (as dragonmech is). But I want to leave the question open for a bit longer, just in case someone have a good approach in adding the mech as part of the cr. My version of Eberron isn't gonna be that centered on mech, they will be there, but not as common as in Dragonmech.